# TypeError: create_superuser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I need to create custom user model because I need to have one additional field called role. If the role is provided, it should be assigned to the user model otherwise provide agent as role in user model. I inherited the `AbstractUser`. This way when creating the user, first the password is saved as plain text and another is user cannot login it says unable to login. So i tried the below way as in docs but the problem is i don't need the email part so i excluded it and used just username and password but getting error like `TypeError: create_superuser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'`

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
        def create_user(self, username, password=None):
            """
            Creates and saves a User with the given username, date of
            birth and password.
            """
            if not username:
                raise ValueError('Users must have an username')
            user = self.model(username=username)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save(using=self._db)
            return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given username and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            username=username,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Role(models.Model):

    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('agent', 'Agent'),
        ('agency', 'Agency'),
        ('manufacturer', 'Manufacturer'),
    )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=ROLE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.role


class User(AbstractUser):

    role = models.ForeignKey(
        Role,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=User)
def add_role_to_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print('instance in add role', instance)
    if kwargs.get('created'):
        try:
            role = Role.objects.get(user=instance)
            print('role', role)
        except Role.DoesNotExist:
            Role.objects.create(role="agent")
        try:
            token = Token.objects.get(user=instance)
            print('token', token)
        except Token.DoesNotExist:
            Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are *not using email* in **`create_superuser()`** you can add email as a keywork parameter and set to a `None` as

```
def create_superuser(self, username, password, email=None):
    """
    Creates and saves a superuser with the given username and password.
    """
    user = self.create_user(
        username=username,
        password=password,
    )
    user.is_superuser = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

Comment: Thanks that got solved but i get You don't have permission to edit anything.

Comment: I don't understand :(

Comment: I solved it using user.is_superuser = True. I thought user.is_admin = True will work.

Answer (score 0):

you can just add `*args, **kwargs` in the function.

like this

```
def create_superuser(self, username, password, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Creates and saves a superuser with the given username and password.
    """
    user = self.create_user(
        username=username,
        password=password,
    )
    user.is_superuser = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```